# #ajax response handler function

Tags: 7, ajax

Hi I am using #ajax in my custom form. I need a response handler function for my form in jquery. How can i acheive this goal?

For example:

```
$form['changethis'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => array(
  'one' => 'one',
  'two' => 'two',
  'three' => 'three',
),
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_example_simplest_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
 ),
);
```

Here i have the ajax_example_simplest_callback in php. I need a response handler in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(function($) {

  Drupal.YOUR_MODULE_NAME = {
    form_id: 'FORM_ID'  
  };

  Drupal.behaviors.YOUR_MODULE_NAME = {
   attach: function(context, settings) {

    for (ajax_el in settings.ajax) {
      if (Drupal.ajax[ajax_el].element.form) {
        if (Drupal.ajax[ajax_el].element.form.id === Drupal.YOUR_MODULE_NAME.form_id) {
          Drupal.ajax[ajax_el].success = Drupal.YOUR_MODULE_NAME.success;
       }
      }
     }
    }   
   };


 Drupal.YOUR_MODULE_NAME.success = function (response, status) {
    // HERE YOU GET THE response
 }

 });
```

Comment: Love this approach, but my success function is never called. If anyone else has similar trouble check out my new question and (hopefully) it's corresponding answers: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73035/trouble-with-jquery-handler-function-for-ajax-response

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) modules.  ajax_example module has a number of examples.

eg. [dependent dropdown](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/ajax_example/ajax_example.module#l77)

Comment: I check this examples. Please consider the question before answering. 'Here i have the ajax_example_simplest_callback in php. I need a response handler in js.'

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, you can add js response by   $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_*() 
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cleanest way of doing things but does the job none the less...

```
'#ajax' => array(
  'progress' => array(
    'type' => 'throbber',
    'message' => '<script>YOUR_CUSTOM_HANDLER(); </script>',
  ),
```